# Count the total of cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I had a dataframe as below by recording the number of cases per month:

```
Month         client      Cases       
2019-06-01      A           1
2019-05-01      A           0
2019-04-01      A           0
2019-03-01      A           2
2019-02-01      A           0
2019-06-01      B           1
2019-05-01      B           1
2019-04-01      B           0
2019-03-01      B           0
2019-02-01      B           0
```

I would like to accumulated number per month by clients as below:

```
Month         client      Cases       
2019-06-01      A           3
2019-05-01      A           2
2019-04-01      A           2
2019-03-01      A           2
2019-02-01      A           0
2019-06-01      B           2
2019-05-01      B           1
2019-04-01      B           0
2019-03-01      B           0
2019-02-01      B           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the cumulative sum.

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
        Month  Cases
0  2019-06-01      1
1  2019-05-01      0
2  2019-04-01      0
3  2019-03-01      2
4  2019-02-01      0

In [4]: df.Cases[::-1].cumsum()
Out[4]:
4    0
3    2
2    2
1    2
0    3
Name: Cases, dtype: int64
```

This is where `pandas` automatic index alignment shines:

```
In [5]: df['Cases'] = df.Cases[::-1].cumsum()

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
        Month  Cases
0  2019-06-01      3
1  2019-05-01      2
2  2019-04-01      2
3  2019-03-01      2
4  2019-02-01      0
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I need to accumulate the value by client?

Comment: @JennyJingYu then likely you'll have to use some form of `.groupby`